# how to read file line by line and store value in array using shell script

Tags: shell

How to read file line by line and store each line value in different array variable. For example `file.txt` contains below lines:

```
abc;2;1;3;4;5;6;7 
cba;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;
......
.......
```

So I need to read line by line and store each line value seprated by delimeter in different variable. Like for line 1

```
arr[0]=abc, arr[1]=2, arr[2]=1 and so on
```

and after reading first line it will read line 2 and store its value like:

```
arr[0]=cba, arr[1]=1, arr[2]=2 and so on
```

I have tried below code

```
while read line
do
    arr+=("$line")
done <$file

for ((i=0; i < ${#arr[*]}; i++))
do
    echo "${arr[i]}"

done
```

But in this case I am getting whole line by line in `arr[i]`. I need to store this value of line in seprate variable as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using bash:

```
while read line; do
    varname=${line%%;*}
    IFS=';' read -a $varname <<< $line
done < file
```

- read the file line by line
- determine the name of the variable using *bash*'s substring math
- read into array using `read -a`

---

```
$ echo ${abc[0]} ${abc[1]}
abc 2
$ echo ${cba[0]} ${cba[1]}
cba 1
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.. but in my case  <<< its not working. its giving error for this symbol <<<.

Comment: As I wrote, I'm assuming you are using bash. What shell are you using?